# Export to PDF error using Dot Net Report Builder

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, report

I am using the MVC version of the Dot Net Report Builder. I am able to configure dotnetreport and run a test report, but if I click on Export to PDF I get a javascript error - unexpected token export. Looking at the javascript console error it seems to be originating from bootstrap/popper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out, this is because popper.js needs to be included from /umd folder instead of the root folder.

This is fixed in the latest nuget package for dotnetreport now. You can either update your nuget package or just change the reference to popper.js in the layout file to /umd/popper.js.